# Symfony code accessing protected property should throw error but doesn't

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 3.4.17 there's a line in `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php` that triggers a PHpStorm warning:

```
$this->createCacheItem = \Closure::bind(
        function ($key, $value, $isHit) use ($defaultLifetime) {
            $item = new CacheItem();
            $item->key = $key; //directly accessing protected property!
            $item->value = $value;
            $item->isHit = $isHit;
            $item->defaultLifetime = $defaultLifetime;

            return $item;
        },
        null,
        CacheItem::class
    );
```

The property $key, $value etc are protected properties of CacheItem();.

PHP should throw an exception when accessing protected proprties directly, I double checked it with this script:

```
<?php
class test {
    protected $a = '';
}
$test= new test();
$test->a = 'b';
var_dump($test);
```

This throws 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property test::$a'.

Why is the Symfony code running without problems but is my script (correctly) failing?

Comment: And `Closure::bind` binds a closure (function) to an object. And that function __has access__ to object it is binded to.

Comment: Ah I see, the CacheItem class is passed to the function..if you post an answer I'll accept it